# Windows 7 become slow when ever connected to LAN. Goes back to normal when the LAN is removed

Tags: windows-7, networking, lan

One of our Windows 7 Machine (Laptop) is experiencing a physical network issue.
Using WiFi has no problem but whenever I connect the LAN cable, the system becomes slow.
Opening files, emails, or even the Task Manager becomes ridiculously slow.

And then whenever I remove the LAN cable, the system suddenly becomes responsive again.
Then sometimes when I connect back again the LAN cable it becomes normal. However after leaving the LAN connected for some time the issue will arise again.

What do you think is the problem here?

Things I have done so far:
 1. Update network drivers 
 2. Changed the **Speed & Duplex** of the LAN Properties. (This fixed the issue at some point, however the issue still arises)